# Resolving AT+CIPSTART command response "STATE: IP PROCESSING"

Tags: at-command, sim900

Usually this command response is CONNECT OK, but some time it gives following response.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80
STATE:IP PROCESSING

CONNECT FAIL
```

and status command shows:

```
AT+CIPSTATUS?
+CIPSTATUS:
STATE:IP PROCESSING 

OK
```

How can I get away with this status of IP PROCESSING? I have tried `AT+CIPCLOSE` and `AT+CIPSHUT`, but could not solve the problem and I have to reset the GPRS/GSM module.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

According to [SIM900_TCPIP_Application Note_V1.02](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_TCPIP_Application%20Note_V1.02.pdf) the **IP PROCESSING** state is used only when working with GPRS multi-connection: `AT+CIPMUX=1`
So it's probable that you might have a problem with your multiple connections.

If you don't need to support multiple connections at the same time you can simply use GPRS single connection: `AT+CIPMUX=0` this may solve your problem.

Comment: Actually I am using A9G GPRS/GSM module. And I am not using multiconnection mode. And by default `AT+CIPMUX=0` I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: Check that you have enough signal quality